# Adaptive Filter Gradient Descent

Tags: adaptive-filters, optimization, gradient, convex-optimization

The quadratic performance surface of an adaptive filter is a paraboloid. Its minimum can be found wherever the gradient is zero. However, since there are two types of paraboloids (elliptical and hyperbolic), is there a way to tell if the minimum detected is a global minimum or just a saddle point?

Answer (score 3):

The quadratic surface is determined by the autocorrelation matrix of the data, which is always positive definite or positive semi-definite. This means that any stationary point is always a minimum. In the worst case, this minimum is not unique if the matrix is singular, but it can never be a saddle point.

Comment: Can you please explain how it can never be a saddle point? I assumed that if the quadratic surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid (in which one parabola is turning upwards and the other downwards), a saddle point exists where the gradient is zero.

Comment: @user1832413: If you have a quadratic form $x^TAx+b^Tx$, and if the matrix $A$ is positive (semi-)definite (as is the case with an autocorrelation matrix), then the function defined by the quadratic form is convex and has a minimum. A saddle point can only occur if the matrix $A$ is indefinite.

Comment: for the LMS adaptive filter (Widrow), it can't be a saddle point because the function is magnitude square error which can't go negative.  a minimum point close to zero can only go up on the sides, not down.